# Why does the date part week of 2017-01-01 return 52?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Running the query `select date_part('week','2016-12-31'::date)` returns `52` as expected because this is the last week of 2016.

Running the query `select date_part('week','2017-01-02'::date)` returns `1` as expected because this is the first week of 2017.

**However**, running the query `select date_part('week','2017-01-01'::date)` returns `52` which is wrong.

Is it something to do with 2017-01-01 being a Sunday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html).  `'week'` is based on the ISO week, which is:

> **week**
>
> The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.

Comment: Awsome thanks. I am concatenating the week number with the year. Now I am using the iso year so 2017-01-01 returns 2016-52 using `date_part('isoyear','2017-01-01'::date)` instead of `date_part('year','2017-01-01'::date)` returning 2017-52

Comment: @Worm . . . Exactly the right approach -- use ISO years and weeks.